# $\exp$ of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices of $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{R})$ spans $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to show that any matrix $A \in SL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $n \geq 2$, (ie, $\det A =1$)  can be written as $A= \exp s \ \exp k$, where $s$ is symmetric, and $k$ skew-symmetric, in the Lie algebra of the Lie group $$\mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{R}) = \{ b \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{R}) : \text{tr} \ b =0  \}   $$ and $$\exp: \mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{R}) \to SL(n, \mathbb{R})$$ is the standard exponential of matrices.

So far I showed that $(\exp s)^t = \exp s$ and $(\exp k)^t = -\exp k$ and tried to use these relations but I couldn't really get anything.

Comment: What is the result for $A=\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 0&-1}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I showed that it is not the image of a unique $a \in \mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{R})$, (but it will have to be a product of two).

Comment: Right, this was my question. For which $s,k$ do we have $A=\exp(s)\exp(k)$ for this $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am trying to decompose $A$ as sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix, but the symmetric one I obtain has not null trace. I also tried to do a explicit computation of the exponential with $s= \begin{pmatrix}
a   & b  \\
b   & -a
\end{pmatrix}$ and $k=\begin{pmatrix}
0   & c  \\
-c   & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ but I get a enormous expression from which I cannot infer anything.